# Forgot Travel History on Tier 4 - HELP!

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, study

I'm a mature student, Canadian and applied for the Tier 4 Visa a week ago. I was filling out my travel history and forgot 3 trips to the USA - I've been travelling abroad for a few years now and while filling out the online application didn't think to add my USA trips. I know this was careless and I feel terrible but any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Has anyone been refused due to travel history being left out?? What can I do!

Comment: I've never filled in an application for visas, so I am not an expert in these matters, but couldn't call a number and ask for help. There must be a number or an email address that you can write to. I think if you explain that you made a mistake, it's more likely officials won't think you were covering up something.

Comment: Have you attended your bio-metrics appointment/interview already?

Comment: I attended the biometrics appointment last week and received confirmation they had my application and were considering it on Monday.

Comment: A Tier 4 visa application for a Canadian is unlikely to be refused for a few overlooked trips to the US. You [could contact the UKVI help centre](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english), a fee-based service, but it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A Tier 4 visa application for a Canadian is unlikely to be refused for a few overlooked trips or border crossings into the United States.

As you've already been interviewed and your biometrics provided, you could contact the UKVI help centre, a fee-based service, if it continues to worry you:

> [**Contact UK Visas and Immigration**](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english)
>
> You can call or email English-speaking staff with a question about your application.
>
> **By phone**
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> **By email**
>   [**Email UK Visas and Immigration**](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English). 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and UK public holidays.